# startActivityForResult(...) immediately returns 0

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

When I call `startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), VkAuth.class), VK_ID);` on Samsung (on HTC and Nexus everything works fine), `onActivityResult` with requestCode == VK_ID and result code 0 (Cancelled) is called before the VkAuth Activity is created.
The parent Activity has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.   `startActivityForResult` is called from a Fragment attached to the parent Activity.
Log

```
E/AuthenticationFragment: vkLogIn
E/AuthenticationFragment: startActivityForResult 9101
E/AuthenticationFragment: onPause
E/MainActivity: onPause
E/MainActivity: onActivityResult before super: request - 271245, result - 0
E/AuthenticationFragment: request - 9101, result - 0
E/MainActivity: onActivityResult after super: request - 271245, result - 0
E/AuthenticationFragment: onPause
E/MainActivity: onPause
E/VkAuth: onCreate
E/VkAuth: onResume
```

Comment: do you see anything suspicious on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink nothing really, activity and fragment calls onPause and then onActivityResult with result 0

Comment: btw is it your activity (the called one) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after i removed android:launchMode="singleInstance", this misbehaivior stoped

Comment: Just wasted several hours trying to debug this issue, and this answer definitely solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar behaviour on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2 API 17.
I was starting an Activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CUSTOM_CODE);
```

However the `onActivityResult` got called immediately with `resultCode=0` (`ACTIVITY.RESULT_CANCELED`). It was working perfectly fine on other devices.

Based on what @Yarh said, i looked in AndroidManifest and figured out that the Activity that executed the `startActivityForResult` has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.

Removing this line definitely fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have not posted enough code for us to really see what is going on but I would check the following:

When you return from the activity you have just started up using `startActivityForResult`, please check whether you have `setResult` to `RESULT_OK`:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Comment: cancell is returened after startActivityForResult, but `before` activity is even created, so it is not a point of misplaced setResult